# Simulated Click not firing event on GWT site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gwt, vaadin

I am attempting to automate testing on the client side of a **GWT** built site with **VAADIN** as a framework.

I have been able to run through the all the DOM elements and find the one div that contains the "*button*". (It not a button, just text styled to look like a button.) I tried the `click()` method but it never fires.

This can only be done on the client-side. I cannot adjust the source code to contain any ID's or names. I only have the method for locating the button.

Here is my Javascript code from the scratch pad. This does find the div that contains the "*button*".

```
var bDivClass = "v-rasterlayout-slot";
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName(bDivClass);

for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
     divs[i].click();
    if(divs[i].textContent.localeCompare("Submit Query") == 0){
        console.log("Submit Button found \n" + divs[i].innerHTML);
        divs[i].click();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUTS:** 
[image]

If I inspect the element, I can see a couple of the DIVs have click listeners attached.

[image]

Here is the event listener. It is the same for both the child and the parent.

[image]

How do I simulate a click on that div?

Comment: Can you explain purpose of jQuery tag???

Comment: I meant you have tagged your question with jQuery but said `using only JavaScript`, that's quite ambiguous imho

Comment: Yikes, I guess I meant the JavaScript family. I have jQuery available.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `getElementsByClassName()` returns only one top-level-in-that-context element which has no event listeners attached. If you want to simulate a click on every child of that element you need to iterate over *childs*. Your loop actually doesn't do that.